# Why does ASeq require a collection to implement Sequential to allow equivalence?

Tags: clojure

I'm writing my own `range` that implements `ISeq`. My original implementation for `equiv` was just calling `seq` on my range and the other list, and comparing using `=`:

```
(defn equals? [this-range other-range]
  (= (seq this-range) (seq other-range)))
```

This seemed fine, but then I ran into some odd behavior:

```
(= (new-range 5 10)
   (range 5 10))
=> true

(= (range 5 10)
   (new-range 5 10))
=> false ; Uh oh
```

Where `new-range` is my custom constructor.

To see how `LongRange` handles equivalence, I checked its source. It delegates to `ASeq`, and `ASeq`'s `equiv` method starts with the lines:

```
public boolean equiv(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Sequential) && !(obj instanceof List)) {
        return false;
. . .
```

Since my range doesn't implement `Sequential` or `List`, this check fails. It doesn't even try to iterate my range to do a value comparison.

What's the reasoning here? `Sequential` is just an empty interface. It seems to just exist to "mark" classes as being sequential without requiring any methods.

I could just have my range implement `Sequential` to allow the check, but I'm wondering if my equivalence function should include the same check as `ASeq` as well. It seems like an unnecessary check though, as `seq` will already fail on a bad argument via `clojure.lang.RT/seqFrom`.

What is the purpose for the `Sequential` check, should I implement `Sequential` to appease such methods, and should I do such a check as well in similar methods?

Comment: Perhaps an answer can be distilled from this link: https://insideclojure.org/2016/03/16/collections/#equality

Comment: @glts Thanks. I'll give that a read over. Alex's material is always interesting.

Comment: As an aside, it really is a giant pain to implement your own types that fully participate in Clojure's collection framework. It's been a long time since I tried, and I don't remember the details, but when I did try there were rough edges like "if you don't implement java.util.List, some functions in clojure.lang will explode". You really need to implement almost everything in `(supers (class '(1)))` to be a real sequence (again, last I checked). I mention this since you said you don't implement List, and that could cause a problem.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks. I'll explore that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What return value would you like to get from

```
(= [1 2] #{1 2})
```

or from

```
(= '([1 2]) {1 2})
```

? In both cases, the two collections are indistinguishable after you `seq` them (depending on how `#{1 2}` gets hashed, anyway). But they clearly are not equal collections: maps and sets behave very differently from lists and vectors. The main thing distinguishing each pair is that one of them is Sequential (intended for use in a sequential manner) and the other is not. That's what this tagging interface is for.

So, yes, you should check Sequential before declaring your sequential object to be equal to some other object: it cannot reasonably be equal to anything non-sequential.

Comment: Ahh. In retrospect, that makes perfect sense. Thank you.